# How to Group Objects in a List into other Lists by Attribute using streams & Java 8?

Tags: list, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I want to group a List of Objects containing a `time` attribute into 5-Minute intervals, preferably using streams and collectors.

The only possible solution I found on StackOverflow is to calculate how many intervals (sublists) I need, add every object to every one of these Lists and filter out the ones that dont fit into the respective timeframe, which is not exactly a nice solution.

(You can find the Thread here: [How to group elements of a List by elements of another in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245142/how-to-group-elements-of-a-list-by-elements-of-another-in-java-8))

I thought of something similar to this:

```
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
.......
List<List<MyObject>> grouped = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(obj -> obj.getTime() / intervalLength));
```

This of course doenst work.

I hope that, with Java 8 & its features being used more and more, we can find a suting solution for such a Problem.

Regards,
Claas M.

EDIT:
In the End, I used @Harsh Poddar's solution and converted the Map into a List of Lists using

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer, List<MyObject>> entry:map.entrySet())
  list.add(entry.getValue());
```

Note: The List had to be sorted afterwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works totally fine:

```
Map<Long,<List<MyObject>> grouped = ticks.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(obj -> obj.getTime() / intervalLength));
```

This method will give you a map on which you may then call .values() to get the list of lists. First element will contain elements with obj.getTime() from 0 to intervalLength provided there were such elements. The second will contain from intervalLength to intervalLength*2 and so on

Answer (score 4):

Use a function to map a time to a bucket:

```
// assume time is in seconds
int bucketNumber(int baseTime, int thisTime) {
    return (thisTime - baseTime) / 300;
}
```

Then collect by bucket number:

```
ticks.stream().collect(groupingBy(e -> bucketNumber(baseTime, e.getTime()));
```

Now you have a `Map<Integer, List<Tick>>` where the key is the index of the five-minute bucket starting at `baseTime`, and a list of ticks in that bucket.  If you just want a histogram, use a downstream collector:

```
ticks.stream().collect(groupingBy(e -> bucketNumber(baseTime, e.getTime()), 
                                  counting());
```

Comment: @HarshPoddar Up to you.  I was trying to illustrate how to break the problem down, since that seemed to be where the OP was having trouble.