# Group a list of Object arrays by timestamp in Java

Tags: java, list, datetime, timestamp, grouping

I have a List < Object[]> and one of the columns in the Object[] is a LocalDateTime. The other columns are a location (String) and an item price (Double).

Basically, my list looks like this:

```
2017-01-01 02:05:00   NEWYORK   26.89
2017-01-01 02:10:00   NEWYORK   72.00
2017-01-01 02:15:00   NEWYORK   73.10
2017-01-01 02:20:00   NEWYORK   70.11
2017-01-01 02:25:00   NEWYORK   79.90
2017-01-01 02:30:00   NEWYORK   72.33
2017-01-01 02:35:00   NEWYORK   75.69
2017-01-01 02:40:00   NEWYORK   72.12
2017-01-01 02:45:00   NEWYORK   73.09
2017-01-01 02:50:00   NEWYORK   72.67
2017-01-01 02:55:00   NEWYORK   72.56
2017-01-01 03:00:00   NEWYORK   72.76

2017-01-01 02:05:00   BOSTON    26.89
2017-01-01 02:10:00   BOSTON    42.00
2017-01-01 02:15:00   BOSTON    23.10
2017-01-01 02:20:00   BOSTON    77.11
2017-01-01 02:25:00   BOSTON    49.92
2017-01-01 02:30:00   BOSTON    72.63
2017-01-01 02:35:00   BOSTON    73.19
2017-01-01 02:40:00   BOSTON    76.18
2017-01-01 02:45:00   BOSTON    83.59
2017-01-01 02:50:00   BOSTON    76.67
2017-01-01 02:55:00   BOSTON    52.06
2017-01-01 03:00:00   BOSTON    76.06
```

What I need to do is a time-weighted average of the price over an interval of 15-minutes, per city. The DateTime associated to the interval is the latest one. So running my algorithm over the list above would produce another List that looks like this:

```
01-01-2017 02:15:00   NEWYORK   57.33 (average of 2:05, 2:10 and 2:15)
01-01-2017 02:30:00   NEWYORK   74.11 (average of 2:20, 2:25 and 2:30)
01-01-2017 02:45:00   NEWYORK   73.63 (...)
01-01-2017 03:00:00   NEWYORK   72.60
01-01-2017 02:15:00   BOSTON    30.66 (average of 2:05, 2:10 and 2:15)
01-01-2017 02:30:00   BOSTON    66.55 (average of 2:20, 2:25 and 2:30)
01-01-2017 02:45:00   BOSTON    77.65 (...)
01-01-2017 03:00:00   BOSTON    68.26
```

I'm thinking the first step in doing this is to group the records by 15 minute interval and by city. The rest will simply be a matter of iterating through the groups and getting the average, which I can figure out on my own.

I have no idea how to go about grouping per LocalDateTime and even less on a 15 minute basis. One last thing to mention is there could be missing rows. Some intervals could be empty, in which case we can ignore that interval altogether. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE1**: I'm assuming there is a better way to group them than to sort them and then iterating over each one and comparing timestamps. Something like the first answer in this post:
[How to Group Objects in a List into other Lists by Attribute using streams & Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30415783/how-to-group-objects-in-a-list-into-other-lists-by-attribute-using-streams-jav)

**UPDATE2**: Also, the timestamps are not necessarily every 5 minutes. They could be at random times and some intervals could have 3 or 5 rows in them.

**UPDATE3**: This is not a duplicate, as this question is about Grouping and not rounding down. I understand how rounding down to 15 minutes could be one way of doing it, but afterwards, I'd have to keep the real timestamps to perform a time-weighted average. This is definitely not the way to do this.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html , there should be a few useful functions here

Comment: Such as? Reading on LocalDateTime was the first thing I did.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round time by seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43937466/round-time-by-seconds),. I know it’s not a very strict duplicate, but I think you should be able to adapt and tailor the answers from there to solve your problem.

Comment: You will probably find the best support for what you are trying to do in [the Time4J library](http://www.time4j.net).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I ended up doing it:

```
    HashMap<LocalDateTime, HashMap<Object, ArrayList<Object[]>>> map = new HashMap<LocalDateTime, HashMap<Object, ArrayList<Object[]>>>();

    for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        Object[] row = data.get(i);

        int minutes = ((LocalDateTime) row[timeFieldIndex]).getMinute();
        int minutesToAdd = ( newIntervalMinutes - minutes % newIntervalMinutes) % newIntervalMinutes;

        LocalDateTime roundedTime = ((LocalDateTime)row[timeFieldIndex]).plusMinutes(minutesToAdd).withSecond(0);

        HashMap<Object, ArrayList<Object[]>> sortFieldMap = map.get(roundedTime);
        if(sortFieldMap == null) {
            sortFieldMap = new HashMap<Object, ArrayList<Object[]>>();
            map.put(roundedTime, sortFieldMap);
        }

        ArrayList<Object[]> rowList = sortFieldMap.get(row[sortFieldIndex]);
        if(rowList == null) {
            rowList = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
            sortFieldMap.put(row[sortFieldIndex], rowList);
        }

        rowList.add(row);
    }
```

So the steps are:

1. Get the current row
2. Calculate the minutes to add to round up to the nearest 15 minutes
3. Get the timestamp for the interval (variable roundedTime)
4. See if we already have an entry for this interval. If we don't, create a new map to sort by location (sortFieldMap).
5. See if we already have a list of rows for this specific interval and location. If we don't, create a new list of rows in the map.
6. The structure is there, so add the row to the group.

Now variable map contains all my rows, grouped by time interval and location.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but I want to round up (not down) the intervals. So basically, minutes ending in :05, :10 and :15 should be part of interval :15 and so on. This is why I have "newIntervalMinutes - (minutes % newIntervalMinutes)". This brings another problem though, for whole quarters, since the result of the calculation is 15. And since I don't want to add 15 minutes, I only take the mod of that calculation, which is 0. Does that make sense? It's getting late here :)

Comment: Nice. If the time in the row is `2017-09-14T02:15:50`, this gets rounded down to `2017-09-14T02:15`. I think you intended `2017-09-14T02:30` in this case? (Forget my previous comment, I was wrong on that one.)

Comment: Rather than `withSecond(0)` I recommend `truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES)` since this will also relieve you of any fraction of second.

Answer (score 1):

Design a class to hold your data instead of your `Object` arrays. Each object of your class would hold a timestamp, a location and an item price. It may also hold the result of rounding the timestamp down to whole 15 minutes; alternatively just a method to do this rounding down. As I understand, you can do the rounding (otherwise there’s inspiration to found in [this question: Round time by seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43937466/round-time-by-seconds)).

With such a class you can use the stream from [the answer you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30417534/5772882) to group and average. If you prefer, you may even start your stream from your `List <Object[]>` and map each array into an object before further processing.

**EDIT** I seem to understand that you prefer to do this without a class for your rows. Of course it can be done:

```
private static List<Object[]> averageByQuarterOfHour(final int indexOfTime, 
        int otherGroupingIndex, int indexToAverage, List<Object[]> myList) {
    return myList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(arr 
                    -> Arrays.asList(roundUpToWholeQuarterOfHour((LocalDateTime) arr[indexOfTime]), 
                            arr[otherGroupingIndex])))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(e -> new Object[] { e.getKey().get(0), 
                    e.getKey().get(1), 
                    e.getValue().stream()
                            .map(arr -> (Number) arr[indexToAverage])
                            .mapToDouble(Number::doubleValue)
                            .average()
                            .getAsDouble() })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

static LocalDateTime roundUpToWholeQuarterOfHour(LocalDateTime timeToRound) {
    LocalDateTime truncated = timeToRound.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
    int minute = truncated.getMinute();
    if (truncated.isEqual(timeToRound) && minute % 15 == 0) { // already on a whole quarter
        return timeToRound;
    }
    int minutesToAdd = 15 - (minute % 15);
    return truncated.plusMinutes(minutesToAdd);
}
```

Feeding your list into `averageByQuarterOfHour()` gives:

```
[2017-01-01T03:00, NEWYORK, 72.66333333333334]
[2017-01-01T02:15, NEWYORK, 57.330000000000005]
[2017-01-01T02:30, NEWYORK, 74.11333333333333]
[2017-01-01T02:45, NEWYORK, 73.63333333333334]
[2017-01-01T02:45, BOSTON, 77.65333333333334]
[2017-01-01T03:00, BOSTON, 68.26333333333334]
[2017-01-01T02:15, BOSTON, 30.663333333333338]
[2017-01-01T02:30, BOSTON, 66.55333333333333]
```

I will leave the sorting to you.

You may want to think twice though. A class for your rows may have the advantage of better modelling, which would impact your entire application, not just the average calculation, though on the other hand it would probably require you to model each of your entities separately, with what ever data that entity holds. More locally, a class, even just an auxiliary class holding your array and a method for getting the quarter of the hour, might still make the above code more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, these are good ideas. The use of a class is not really an option for me, as I am fetching the data from SQL tables and the number of columns can vary. All other fields need to stay the same as the original data. So I am effectively passing to the function the List <Object[]> along with 3 integers: 1- The index of the time field. 2- The index of the other grouping field(in this case: Location). 3- The index of the field to average.

Comment: Maybe an option would be to have a class that contains an Object[], but this seems overdoing it.

Comment: Yes, @VincentL, that’s certainly an option. I too would consider it. You can better than I weigh the pros and cons compared to primitive sorting and iterating.

Answer (score 0):

Althought there is solution for this question, I tried to write on my own.
Maybe another solution ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Demo> list = new ArrayList<>();
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
    Demo demo = new Demo(Timestamp.valueOf(now),"Beijing",66.40);
    list.add(demo);

    demo = new Demo(Timestamp.valueOf(now.plusMinutes(10)),"Beijing",60.40);
    list.add(demo);

    demo = new Demo(Timestamp.valueOf(now.plusMinutes(16)),"Beijing",80.40);
    list.add(demo);

    Map map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> roundUp(e.timestamp.toLocalDateTime())));

    System.out.println(map);
}


public static String roundUp(LocalDateTime time){
    LocalDateTime temp;
    int minutesSinceLastWhole15 = time.getMinute() % 15;
    if (minutesSinceLastWhole15 >= 8) { // round up
        temp = time.plusMinutes(15 - minutesSinceLastWhole15);
    } else { // round down
        temp = time.minusMinutes(minutesSinceLastWhole15);
    }
    return temp.toString();
}

static class Demo{
    Timestamp timestamp;
    String city;
    Double price;

    public Demo(Timestamp timestamp, String city, Double price){
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.city = city;
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{ timestamp:"+timestamp+" city:"+city+" price:"+price+" }";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, my example wasn't very good. There could be random timestamps in there as well, not necessarily every 5 minutes. Original question was updated.

Comment: sort them, pick the lowest time as your base time. Next keep a running total of prices while the entries times is less than base time + 15. Get average once you go over and reset base time to base time + 15

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to avoid, as mentioned in UPDATE1.

Comment: Why wouldn't adapting this solution be reasonable:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30415783/how-to-group-objects-in-a-list-into-other-lists-by-attribute-using-streams-jav

Answer (score -1):

To make it simpler for demo, I convert your Object[] into CityValue

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args) throws Exception {
        makeList(900).values().stream().forEach(cityValues -> {
            cityValues.forEach(cityValue -> {
                System.out.println(cityValue.toString());
            });
            System.out.println(" ------- ");
        });
     }


     private static Map<Double, List<CityValue>>  makeList(int second) throws ParseException {
        List<CityValue> CityValues = new ArrayList<>();
        CityValues.add(new CityValue("2017-01-01 02:05:00", "NEWYORK", 26.89));
        CityValues.add(new CityValue("2017-01-01 02:10:00", "NEWYORK", 72.00));
        CityValues.add(new CityValue("2017-01-01 02:15:00", "NEWYORK", 73.10));
        CityValues.add(new CityValue("2017-01-01 02:20:00", "NEWYORK", 70.11));
        CityValues.add(new CityValue("2017-01-01 02:25:00", "NEWYORK", 79.90));
        CityValues.add(new CityValue("2017-01-01 02:30:00", "NEWYORK", 72.33));
        CityValues.add(new CityValue("2017-01-01 02:35:00", "NEWYORK", 75.69));
        CityValues.add(new CityValue("2017-01-01 02:40:00", "NEWYORK", 72.12));
        CityValues.add(new CityValue("2017-01-01 02:45:00", "NEWYORK", 73.09));
        CityValues.add(new CityValue("2017-01-01 02:50:00", "NEWYORK", 72.67));
        CityValues.add(new CityValue("2017-01-01 02:55:00", "NEWYORK", 72.56));
        CityValues.add(new CityValue("2017-01-01 03:00:00", "NEWYORK", 72.76));

        CityValues.add(new CityValue("2017-01-01 02:05:00", "BOSTON",  26.89));
        CityValues.add(new CityValue("2017-01-01 02:10:00", "BOSTON",  42.00));
        CityValues.add(new CityValue("2017-01-01 02:15:00", "BOSTON",  23.10));
        CityValues.add(new CityValue("2017-01-01 02:20:00", "BOSTON",  77.11));
        CityValues.add(new CityValue("2017-01-01 02:25:00", "BOSTON",  49.92));
        CityValues.add(new CityValue("2017-01-01 02:30:00", "BOSTON",  72.63));
        CityValues.add(new CityValue("2017-01-01 02:35:00", "BOSTON",  73.19));
        CityValues.add(new CityValue("2017-01-01 02:40:00", "BOSTON",  76.18));
        CityValues.add(new CityValue("2017-01-01 02:45:00", "BOSTON",  83.59));
        CityValues.add(new CityValue("2017-01-01 02:50:00", "BOSTON",  76.67));
        CityValues.add(new CityValue("2017-01-01 02:55:00", "BOSTON",  52.06));
        CityValues.add(new CityValue("2017-01-01 03:00:00", "BOSTON",  76.06));
        return CityValues.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(cityValue -> Math.ceil(cityValue.getDate().getTime() / (second * 1000))));
    }
}

class CityValue {
    static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD hh:mm:ss");
    Date date;
    String cityName;
    float price;

    public CityValue(String date, String cityName, double price) throws ParseException {
        this.cityName = cityName;
        this.price = (float) price;
        this.date = sdf.parse(date);
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return this.date;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return sdf.format(this.date) + " " + this.cityName + "  " + this.price;
    }
}
```